# Find max nested elements that can be retrieved, given a max sliding range

Tags: python, algorithm

Given multiple array of array of elements `T_n`,

```
T_0 = [[0,2], [1,8], [5,9], [2,4], [7,8], [10,10]] 
T_1 = [[7,10], [11,13], [20,25]]
```

where the first index of each element array indicates the start "time" and the second index the "end" time of each entity, for example `[0,2]` means start = 0, end = 2. (start and end time can be the same as well, in which case, its a "free" entity. Entity refers to an array in the array of arrays)

and a max "stay time"

```
M = 2
```

Example:

Given just one T,

```
T_0 = [[0,2], [1,8], [5,9], [2,4], [7,8], [10,10]] 

M = 2
```

The max number of entities will be 4, since
I can "stay" from start = 0 to end = 2, so I will attain the entities `[0,2], [1,8], [2,4]`, on top of the free entity `[10,10]`. Since there is only 1 T, the `T_n` that gives me the max entities will simply be `T_0`

Another Example

Given two Ts,

```
T_0 = [[0,2], [2,4]]
T_1 = [[7,10], [11,13], [20,25]]

M = 2
```

I can get 2 entities from `T_0` by "staying" from start = 1 and end = 3.
I can also get 2 entities from `T_1` by "staying from start = 9 and end = 11.
So, the max entities i can get is 2. And the T that will give me the max number of entities is both `T_0` and `T_1`, since they give the same number of entities.

**So the question is**: How do I find an algorithm that gives me the maximum number of entities I can attain, and which `T_n` will give me this max number of entities?

I have tried something like a sliding window method, but I don't think it is the most efficient way, and was wondering if there is another way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm should give the max number of attained events in *O(n logn)* for each individual array. Apply that to each array and then pick the best one.

- first, *remove* all the "free" events from the array and store their number in a separate variable
- use two [heaps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) to keep track of `remaining` events sorted by starting time, and `active` events (just the end time)
- since an event counts as attained if it is just "touched" by the time window, test all times in order such that the window's starting time is the ending time of any event, or vice versa
- for each starting time, move events from the `remaining` heap to the `active` heap according to their start time, and remove them from the `active` heap according to their end time
- get the best such window and add the previously determined number of free events

Since you only have to test windows coinciding with the start/end time of the *n* events, and the most complex step are the heap operations with *O(logn)* being applied to each event at most once, overall complexity should be *O(n logn)*.

```
import heapq

def best_window(arr, m):
    free = sum(1 for a, b in arr if a == b)
    cand_times = sorted([a-m for a, b in arr] + [b for a, b in arr])
    remaining = sorted((a, b) for a, b in arr if a != b)
    active = []
    attained = {}
    for t in cand_times:
        while remaining and t + m >= remaining[0][0]:
            a, b = heapq.heappop(remaining)
            heapq.heappush(active, b)
        while active and t > active[0]:
            heapq.heappop(active)
        attained[t] = len(active)
    best = max(attained, key=attained.get)
    return attained[best] + free, best
```